# Can I be denied a tourist visa for UAE after being deported due to a fake employment visa?

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, uae

I was deported in July 2014, on account of fake employment visa. My agent cheated me by altering some information and putting my details on others original employment visa. After reaching Dubai Airport, The immigration officer cleared me everthing and i understood . then i was deported late night on same day without any stamp on the Passport. Now I want to go on visit visa, will my visa get rejected?

Comment: This is not off topic. The OP wants a tourist visa and not a business visa.

Comment: @JoErNanO Why does it become off topic if he wants a business visa?

Comment: @Calchas It does not. There's one close vote as off topic with migration to Expats on the question. The only interpretation I could give of this is that the close-voter read "employment visa" and decided that the question is a better fit for Expats. So yes I should have written employment rather than business.

Answer (score 6):

There is unfortunately a very good chance of your visa application getting rejected.

When you are denied entry to a country, the immigration officers do not usually place a stamp. But they do keep record of your information. In some cases, you will have the right to refuse to give your biometric data (finger prints for example), but your passport number, name, birthday, etc will be recorded nonetheless.

If your real intention is to visit the country, your best odds would be if you apply after some time. Being denied entry with a fake visa and then applying for a tourist visa is a strong sign that the applicant is probably an immigrant.

In most countries, providing forged documents is a serious offense.

If you still would like to visit there for tourist purpose, provide strong evidence that you have a stable source of income in your home country. Other travel history (other visa stamps that you were allowed to enter and left in time) will help too.

Comment: Its overs one year now. Can I get emplyment visa? And I did not went there on the fake visa, it was the recruitment Agent who did all this.

Comment: It will depend on the application. I'm sorry the visa wasn't real last time. Whether it was prepared by yourself or the recruitment agency, it's _your_ passport that contained the visa. In most cases, those information recorded in embassies are retained for a certain time that we don't really know.

Comment: Also attach an explanation that you were the victim of a dirty recruiting agent, it was not your intent to fake a visa.